# How to add a group to multiple groups in Doxygen without sacrificing document readability

Tags: nested, doxygen

I have 4 groups, G1 to G4, documented as follows in Doxygen.

```
/**
@defgroup G1 Group 1
@brief A brief description of group 1.
*/

/**
@defgroup G2 Group 2
@brief A brief description of group 2.
*/

/**
@defgroup G3 Group 3
@brief A brief description of group 3.
*/

/**
@defgroup G4 Group 4
@brief A brief description of group 4.
*/
```

I want them to be grouped in three different ways - 1) all, 2) group of odd, and 3) group of even. I did the following to achieve this.

```
/**
@defgroup all_groups All groups
@{
    @defgroup G1
    @defgroup G2
    @defgroup G3
    @defgroup G4
@}
*/

/**
@defgroup odd_groups Odd groups
@{
    @defgroup G1
    @defgroup G3
@}
*/

/**
@defgroup even_groups Even groups
@{
    @defgroup G2
    @defgroup G4
@}
*/
```

It works with doxygen-1.8.13. However, it is illegal. Because as per Doxygen documentation, `defgroup` should be used only once per group.

A proper implementation should be

```
/**
@defgroup G1 Group 1
@ingroup all_groups odd_groups
@brief A brief description of group 1.
*/

/**
@defgroup G2 Group 2
@ingroup all_groups even_groups
@brief A brief description of group 2.
*/

...

/**
@defgroup all_groups All groups
@defgroup odd_groups Odd groups
@defgroup even_groups Even groups
*/
```

or

```
/**
@defgroup all_groups All groups

    @addtogroup G1
    @ingroup all_groups

    @addtogroup G2
    @ingroup all_groups

    @addtogroup G3
    @ingroup all_groups

    @addtogroup G4
    @ingroup all_groups 
*/

/**
@defgroup odd_groups Odd groups

    @addtogroup G1
    @ingroup odd_groups

    @addtogroup G3
    @ingroup odd_groups
*/

/**
@defgroup even_groups Even groups

    @addtogroup G2
    @ingroup even_groups

    @addtogroup G4
    @ingroup even_groups    
*/
```

However, the readability vanishes. In either case, the documentation is not easy to read and maintain. I searched the net for a possible workaround, but in vain. Am I missing some elegant solution?

I would prefer something like `@addgroup` keyword to achieve this.

```
/**
@defgroup all_groups All groups
@{
    @addgroup G1
    @addgroup G2
    @addgroup G3
    @addgroup G4
@}
*/

/**
@defgroup odd_groups Odd groups
@{
    @addgroup G1
    @addgroup G3
@}
*/

/**
@defgroup even_groups Even groups
@{
    @addgroup G2
    @addgroup G4
@}
*/
```

Comment: "However, it is illegal." No, it is invalid. Illegal means against the law. It is not that.

Comment: Did you have a look at `\snippetdoc` and `\includedoc` commands?